# Is *a+=*b same as int sum = *a+*b where sum = *a?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
void update(int *a,int *b) {
    *a = *a + *b;
    int absDifference = *a - *b > 0 ? *a - *b : -(*a - *b);
    *b = absDifference; 
}
/* 
    void update(int *a,int *b) {
    int sum = *a + *b;
    int absDifference = *a - *b > 0 ? *a - *b : -(*a - *b);
    *a = sum;
    *b = absDifference; 
} */   
int main() {
    int a, b;
    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;
    
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

The upper function is not working on hackerrank but the commented function is working. I don't get the difference.

Comment: You are changing the value of *a and then using it without making a corresponding adjustment to the formula you use it in.

Comment: Welcome to SO:) Please be more specific [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: in C++ you should generally avoid pointers and when pointers are really necessary use smart pointers instead. But normally you should use references

Comment: Unrelated: The absolute diff could be simplified: `int absDifference = *a > *b ? *a - *b : *b - *a;` or better `std::abs(*a - *b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between `*a+=*b` and `int sum = *a+*b` where `sum = *a`.

But! Where you put your condition check makes a lot of difference.

In first function, the `*a` is being added with `*b` and then condition check is for `*a - *b` which is nothing but original (or old) value of `*a`.

```
*a = *a + *b;
int absDifference = *a - *b > 0 ? *a - *b : -(*a - *b);
```

In second function, `*a` is unchanged. Only `sum` is being updated with `*a + *b`. Here the condition is checking for the original `*a` minus `*b`. Only after this condition check, `*a` is being updated.

```
int sum = *a + *b;
int absDifference = *a - *b > 0 ? *a - *b : -(*a - *b);
*a = sum;
```

Equivalent of first function with a intermediate `sum` variable, would be this:

```
int sum = *a + *b;
*a = sum;
int absDifference = *a - *b > 0 ? *a - *b : -(*a - *b);
```

And this is what not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function.

```
int absDifference = *a - *b > 0 ? *a - *b : -(*a - *b);
*a = *a + *b;
*b = absDifference;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your upper function `*a = *a + *b;` *a value had changed.
So `int absDifference = *a - *b > 0 ? *a - *b : -(*a - *b);` this statement result not same with follow function.